# Pay Off Unsubsidized Loan with Subsidized Loan?

Tags: united-states, student-loan, debt, subsidy

I'm currently sitting at about $14,000 USD in loan debt, and am still enrolled at university. I will estimate about $10,000 is unsubsidized, making the remaining $4,000 subsidized. I was fortunate enough to receive some recurring scholarships last semester that will cover all of my expenses - a full ride, essentially. However, my university financial aid office is still offering me certain amounts of subsidized and unsubsidized loans for this semester.

It occurred to me that if I accept the full amount of subsidized loans and use the money to pay the unsubsidized loans, I could essentially convert my debt to being entirely subsidized in a couple semesters.

My question: is there anything wrong with doing this? Would there be some "gotcha" when I finally graduate? Or is this plan really as safe and smart as I think it is?

Comment: Could you edit and add a country tag. Regulations vary from country to country.

Comment: Are the interest rates the same?

Comment: We can assume for all intents and purposes a similar interest rate between the two.

Comment: You disclosed all your scholarships when you applied for financial aid and they still offered you subsidized loans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this, graduated, and did not explode. Based on this fact, I think you can do it too. There are no gotchas I am aware of.

Comment: I've been tricked by my university's financial aid office before; that's how I got into the $14,000 debt, or at least half of it. Thanks for sharing your experience!